# What is the `PM2` for command `yarn run start`?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, pm2

I run the nodejs app with `yarn run start` , what is the command for pm2 I should use?

`pm2 yarn run start` give me an error.

My `package.json` content

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "budo main.js:dist/bundle.js --live --host 0.0.0.0",
    "watch": "watchify main.js -v --debug -o dist/bundle.js",
    "prep": "yarn && mkdirp dist",
    "build": "browserify main.js -o dist/bundle.js",
    "lint": "eslint main.js --fix",
    "deploy": "yarn build && uglifyjs dist/bundle.js -c -m -o dist/bundle.min.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The error you're getting is because a bash script (yarn) is being executed with node...

Because pm2's default interpreter is set to node.

To run yarn you'll have to set the interpreter to bash:

shell:

Try the command below:

```
pm2 start yarn --interpreter bash --name api -- start
```

Comment: Helped me a lot. Let me mention also that if your script name is something else than `start`, then you only have to replace the final `start` by your new script name.
(i.e: `pm2 start yarn --interpreter bash --name api -- start:prod` if I use `yarn run start:prod`).

Comment: is there a way to run this command with sudo access? I got permission access denied when running yarn start on port 80

Answer (score 70):

For me (on ubuntu 20)

```
pm2 start yarn --name api -- start
```

would do the trick. With the bash interpreter flag it would error in pm2.

Comment: Thank you. This should be the top answer

Comment: Hi Christoph. I upvoted your answer. Can you also explain why ?

Comment: Thank you! the bash interpreter flag made it fail on ubuntu 20!

Comment: with option 'watch' , you can make an app enable with watch & reload.
start with *'--watch'* option,  or simply you can restart by 
    `pm2 restart _app-id_ --watch`

Answer (score 9):

my pm2 version is `5.2.0`

`pm2 start "yarn start" --name yourProjec`

Comment: it works for me in version 5.2.2 too

Answer (score 4):

```
pm2 start yarn --name api -- start
```

Won't work for me.

It displays below

```
0|api      | /usr/share/yarn/bin/yarn:2
0|api      | argv0=$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')
0|api      | SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

It means launching a yarn binary file with a node.js

How about this command.

```
pm2 start "yarn start" --name api
```

It work's like charm for me.