# yarn serve in background

Tags: vue.js, npm, cypress, yarnpkg

I'm trying to configure gitlab CI/CD for cypress e2e testing on my vue app which uses yarn for package management. cypress documents are all written for npm [cypress gitlab ci/cd configuration tutorial](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/gitlab-ci)

```
# start the server in the background
- npm run start:ci &
# run Cypress tests
- npx cypress run --browser firefox
```

is there a way to start server in background for yarn? like running yarn serve but in background.

Comment: What makes it run in background is actually this character `&`, can't you just add it to whatever yarn command you use?

Comment: I tried exactly what you say but the thing is, `yarn serve` usually takes about 30 seconds to make the project up and running and cypress tests are running while `yarn serve` has not finished its work yet which results in fail result for all cypress test specs. 
I also tried `&&` but it does only the first part which is `yarn serve` and does not run any cypress test. @pavelsaman

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with the command `yarn serve&`. It will still give you this screen when done compiling:
[image]

I found a way to work around this through [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/) and [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59046950/12846242)

```
pm2 start yarn --interpreter bash --name api -- start
```

Comment: Can you tell me what name=api refers to please. Thanks

Comment: the `--name` flag will name that instance of the script. In this case `api` is the name of my instance.